# Fill NaN values in dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that I created from a text file. Columns B-F should apply to all null fields below them, then once all nulls are filled the next set of periods should be filled by the next values populated in B-F. How would I go about accomplishing this?

[image: Dataframe Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method of DataFrames, with a forward-fill:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Here's a quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, None, None, 5, None, None],
                   'B': [2, None, None, 3, None, None],
                   'C': range(6)})

>>> df
    A   B  C
0   4   2  0
1 NaN NaN  1
2 NaN NaN  2
3   5   3  3
4 NaN NaN  4
5 NaN NaN  5

>>> df.fillna(method='ffill')
   A  B  C
0  4  2  0
1  4  2  1
2  4  2  2
3  5  3  3
4  5  3  4
5  5  3  5
```